# Windows fails to detect file system on Linux CD-ROM iSCSI Target

Tags: linux, windows-8, compact-disc, iscsi

I'm attempting to mount the CD-ROM drive on a machine running Linux to a machine running Windows 8 via iSCSI. `tgtd` is configured on the Linux machine and the Windows iSCSI Initiator succesfully connects and lists two devices (a Disk -1, LUN 0, that I think is actually the controller, and a Disk 0, LUN 1, that is the disk).

In Disk Management it lists the iSCSI mount as 658MB RAW formatted - no file system. Explorer refuses to open the drive, `chkdsk` says that it couldn't identify the file system, etc. But trying to mount the same backing device that `tgtd` is exposing works just fine on the Linux machine. It should be ISO9660 but Windows just seems to not be detecting this.

Any ideas what's wrong here? I'm not even sure if it's misconfigured on the target or initiator side.

Comment: Does diskadministrator show the device as a CDROM drive ? If it shows as DISK it is exported incorrectly from the Linux system. You can also try "isciscli sessionlist" (cmd command) to get additional information on how Windows thinks the iscsi device is configured.

Comment: The disk manager does indeed display it as a CD-ROM drive.

Comment: Then it seems that Windows incorrectly thinks it is a blanco writable CD. I have no idea how to fix that.